# Getting ALL children from all levels

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

im about to develop a Formvalidator. I use a global Function which i call before every form-submit, i also give the form ID for accessing the inputs. so the function looks like this:

```
 function FormValidation(formId)
 {
    var validated = true;

    $("#" + formId ).each(function ()
    {
        var message="";
        if ($(this).attr("data-validation-required") == "true" && $(this).val() == "") {
            message += "-This field is required<br/>";
            validated = false;
        if (message != "")
        $(this).after('<div class="popover fade bottom validation-error in" style="position:relative;display: block; margin-top:0px;"><div class="arrow" style="left:10% !important;"></div><div class="popover-content" style="color:#c0392b;">' + message + '</div></div>');
    }

    return validated; //true or false
  }
```

so the problem is, that this each loop i wrote, is not accessing ALL children which are within the given "form" (by formId). Its accessing only the FIRST level children.

Here's some HTML example code:

```
<form id="myform">
   <input type="text" data-validation-required="true"/>  <-- will be accessed -->
   <div class="SomeDivClass">
      <input type="text" data-validation-required="true"/> <-- will NOT be accessed because 2nd level -->
   </div>
</form>
<script>
    $("#myform").submit(function(){
        if(!FormValidation("myform"))
            return false;
    });
</script>
```

Comment: If you're having trouble with this, I doubt you'll be able to properly write a form validator. Why are you writing your own instead of using one of the many available libraries?

Comment: This is bad code, you are mixing messages that should be localized and html in with javascript. Anyway you would probably be looking for `$("#" + formId ).find('input, textarea, select, radio, checkbox').each(..`

Comment: @Stijn yea i know, its more complicated, thats we had to write an own validator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few issues in the given code

```
function FormValidation(formId) {
    var validated = true;
    //use descendant selector to find all required fields
    $("#" + formId + ' [data-validation-required="true"]').each(function () {
        //check whether the value is empty, if so mark as invalid
        if ($(this).val() == "") {
            var message = "-This field is required<br/>";
            validated = false;
            $(this).after('<div class="popover fade bottom validation-error in" style="position:relative;display: block; margin-top:0px;"><div class="arrow" style="left:10% !important;"></div><div class="popover-content" style="color:#c0392b;">' + message + '</div></div>');
        } else {
            //remove the validation of it is again become valid
            $(this).next('.validation-error').remove()
        }
        //don't return the validated from the each loop since returning false here will cause the each loop to stop further iterations
    })
    return validated; //true or false
}

$("#myform").submit(function () {
    if (!FormValidation("myform")) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/gaEbA/)

Comment: Thanks, but i use also other "validation criteria" e.g. data-validation-maxchars="6"

Comment: There are all sorts of issues with the code — you should try to elaborate on each separately or encourage the user to resolve the original one in detail and then ask other questions for the rest, otherwise we end up with question titles like "jQuery not working" and answers that are basically doing other peoples' work for them without educating.

Comment: @Barney I've added some comments to code, I think that will do

Comment: @Barney what's wrong with you??? i just had a problem and asked this community. I posted code, and asked a clear question. i dont think you'll trying to help here, youre just trying to take your mood out on somebody.

Comment: @BlackOps sorry, it's a perception issue about the StackOverflow Q/A format. I'm not trying to take my mood out — I only posted this comment after posting [my own answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21333479/356541). If this answer resolved your problem, mark it as accepted!

Answer (score 1):

[The jQuery API for traversing the DOM is incredibly well documented](http://api.jquery.com/category/Traversing/). To get all descendants of an element, you'd use [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/), along with a selector that didn't exclude anything — `*` — so your code would end up as follows:

```
$("#" + formId ).find( '*' ).each(function (){
```

But seeing as you're already creating a CSS selector to select the form, you may as well simply extend that selector:

```
$("#" + formId + " *").each(function (){
```

Your current form isn't even iterating the children — it's iterating over each form, and there's only one.

Answer (score 1):

You could get all elements with `data-validation-required` via `$('#' + formId +' [data-validation-required!=""]')`